# How to set the default content type in Spring MVC in no Accept header is provided?

Tags: http, rest, spring-mvc, content-negotiation

If a request is sent to my API without an Accept header, I want to make JSON the default format. I have two methods in my controller, one for XML and one for JSON:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<SearchResultResource> getXmlData(final HttpServletRequest request) {
     //get data, set XML content type in header.
 }

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity<Feed> getJsonData(final HttpServletRequest request){
      //get data, set JSON content type in header.  
 }
```

When I send a request without an Accept header the `getXmlData` method is called, which is not what I want. Is there a way to tell Spring MVC to call the `getJsonData` method if no Accept header has been provided?

**EDIT:**

There is a `defaultContentType` field in the `ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean` that does the trick.

Comment: If you have found a solution using `ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean` add it as a solution.

Answer (score 38):

From the [Spring documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc), you can do this with Java config like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  }
}
```

---

If you are using Spring 5.0 or later, implement `WebMvcConfigurer` instead of extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated since `WebMvcConfigurer` has default methods (made possible by Java 8) and can be implemented directly without the need for an adapter.

Comment: Just a detail: in a Spring boot application, your `@Configuration` class should **not** contain the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation ([source](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-enablewebmvc-and-common-use-cases)). It may prevent other things from working, such as the springfox-swagger-ui html page.

Comment: `WebMvcConigurerAdapter` is deprecated now, just have to change `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` to `implements WebMvcConfigurer`

Comment: Downvoted for misuse of @EnableWebMvc. Spring Boot shouldn't mix with it.

Answer (score 13):

If you use spring 3.2.x, just add this to spring-mvc.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false"/>
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <value>
            json=application/json
            xml=application/xml
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I put this in my servlet-context.xml and it worked perfectly.  Thanks @Larry Z.

Comment: Does setting `mediaTypes` has any effect when `favorPathExtension` is set to `false`?

Comment: mediaTypes is used when favorParameter is set to true. This will check for query params, so /blahblah/4?format=xml would resolve to application/xml. The default value for favorParameter is false, so in this example setting mediaTypes has no effect.

Comment: Hi, after including the above code i am getting json as default if no accept headers. but if i set as application/xml . still im getting the response as json instead of XML?what im missing ?