# How can I globally restrict content type in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on an application where I do not want my rest APIs to receive XML-type requests, and if they do receive such requests they should not be processed and it should directly be filtered in the config of spring boot. How can I achieve it?

Comment: That is what the `consumes` variable is for in `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes true, but I want to disable it for whole application, That'd be for single request right ?

Comment: what you are looking for is interceptors https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor

Comment: Afaik there isn't, however if there is no XML library in your app it won't process XML. If all else fails you can always write a simple filter or Spring `HandlerInterceptor` that checks the content-type/accept-header and disallow the request based on the content-type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the default content type in Spring MVC in no Accept header is provided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189245/how-to-set-the-default-content-type-in-spring-mvc-in-no-accept-header-is-provide)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try to set the default content type in WebConfigurer class and then handle the exception if there is incoming request that does not match the content type you expected via [ControllerAdvice](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-restcontrolleradvice/#:%7E:text=Rest%20Exception%20Handler%20with%20Controller%20Advice%20in%20Spring,-Spring%20supports%20exception&text=The%20%40RestControllerAdvice%20annotation%20is%20specialization,some%20common%20logic%20to%20them.) of your own implementation and extends it with [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html) then provide the handler function for [HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.html) or any other exception you want.